# REST API design: linking resources

Tags: web-services, api, rest

Supposed I have two top-level resources `Foo` and `Bar`. Now the `Foo` need to be linked to some of the `Bar`. In a Java class this might look something like this:

```
public class Foo {

  Set<Bar> bars;
}

public class Bar { … }
```

I'd like to shape the XML representation of `Foo` to something like this:

```
GET /foos/1

<foo>
  …
  <atom:link rel="self" href="/foos/1" />
  <atom:link rel="bars" href="/foos/1/bars" />
</foo>
```

So I pretty much expose all `Bar` **assigned** to a `Foo` as nested resource. That means `Bar` resource have an individual lifecycle (aggregation instead of composition). The nested resource might then expose all linked `Bar` something like this:

```
GET /foos/1/bars

<bars>
  <atom:link rel="bar" href="/foos/1/bars/1" />
  <atom:link rel="bar" href="/foos/1/bars/2" />
</bars>
```

Alteratively I could inline the collection in the `<foo>`element upfront. However I am still stuck with some questions: While this allows me to nicely remove a `Bar` from a `Foo` by triggering a `DELETE` request to e.g. `/foos/1/bars/1` but how would one assign a `Bar` to a `Foo` then? Assuming the client would access `/bars` getting:

```
GET /bars

<bars>
  <bar>
    …
    <atom:link rel="self" href="/bars/4711" />
  </bar>
</bars>
```

and deciding it wants to assign `/bars/1` to `/foo/1/bars`. I was thinking about a `POST` request to `/foo/1/bars` but was unsure about what to actually submit. A `link` element pointing to the `Bar` resource such as the following?

```
POST /foos/1/bars

<atom:link href="/bars/4711" />
```

This seems quite okay as the clients would still not need to create URLs and we still satisfy REST constraints. However it feels a bit weird to `POST` links to the server. Is there a better solution to this scenario?

Comment: I would have no hesitation in POSTing a link to establish a relationship between two resources.  Some people believe you should retrieve the resource and then POST that to be self-descriptive, but I'm not convinced it is necessary.

Comment: That's what I also feel cause you're a) creating unnecessary chattyness and b) don't actual need the entire repesentation on the server side to actually create the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think about this in terms of the resources understood by the server rather than the XML representations that flow in response to (say) a GET request. I have RESTful services that return either JSON or XML, or potentially other representations.

So I agree with your POSTing or PUTing to

```
 /foos/{fooId}/bars
```

to specify either the complete list of bars or the addition of some bars.

The format of the posted payload can be whatever is the natural serialised form for the media-type your're using. In my case it's often a JSON string and so in my service implementation would deserialise and see an array of resoruce reference URL strings.

If your

```
<atom:link href="/bars/4711" />
```

also deserialise nicely then I don't see a problem if the serialised form is a little, um, ornamental.

Summary: do what's natural for your (de)serialiser.

Comment: Actually I don't think that the actual representation matters here. The very same question would arise if I was using JSON. I just chose XML as example here as there's a standard `link` element and I'd have to come up with something myself in JSON. Thanks for your answer nevertheless!

Comment: well the representation in your case has the words atom:link, and I thought that was the cause of your concern. A unique id such as "/bars/4711" seems pretty uncontroversial to me - you've got to have some id, right?

Comment: Right, the reason this probably feels a bit weird to me is that I have sent links from the server to the client only so far to let the client navigate resources. Never had the necessity to POST a link back and been trapped by the feeling the client would have to come up with the URL and thus breaking REST principles. But actually it discovers it up front, so I should be fine.

Comment: @OliverGierke (and djna): +1 this makes sense to me. Any ideas/conclusions as to a `Content-Type` to use for the 'just a link' content where the general content is JSON? `application/json+href` with a body `{ "href"="/bars/4711" }` ? Can find lots of (ATOM) XML-based conventions but having trouble locating any prior art that's JSON based... (Using [HAL](http://blog.stateless.co/post/13296666138/json-linking-with-hal) in general, so something that fits with that would be ideal)

Comment: There's `text/uri-list` for plain line-break separated URIs… http://www.fileformat.info/info/mimetype/text/uri-list/index.htm